# Order of PriorityQueue not as expected

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I have this test:

```
@Test
public void testPrioQueue() {
    PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue());
    pq.add(new SimpleEntry<>("one", 1));
    pq.add(new SimpleEntry<>("three", 3));
    pq.add(new SimpleEntry<>("two", 2));
    List<String> keys = pq.stream().map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("three", "two", "one"), keys);
}
```

I expect the PriorityQueue to order according to my comparator: sort by highest value first. Instead I get this result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[three, two, one]> but was:<[three, one, two]>
```

Is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at `PriorityQueue` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

Same applies to `Stream` instances.

If you want to create a `Stream` instance that would traverse the queue in the order of priorities, you can do something like:

```
Stream.generate(queue::poll).limit(queue.size())
```

Keep in mind that `poll`ing will remove elements from the original queue.

Comment: Curious downvote.

Comment: You should mention that this *consumes* the queue. That is, when it's done, `queue` will be empty.

Comment: @JimMischel sure, good idea :)